# multiple returns function constructor argument

Tags: python

I have a class with two properties and a function that returns two properties.
When i want to initialize new object, why can't I pass this function as constructor argument.

I have found a solution but i want to know WHY first option doesn't work. 
Thanks!

```py
class Box:
    color = None
    size = None
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.color = color
        self.size = size

    def box_properties(self):
        print(self.color,self.size)



def default_box():
    first="Blue"
    second="Medium"
    return first, second


# THIS WORKS :
first, second = default_box()
my_box = Box(first, second)
my_box.box_properties()            


# THIS DOESN'T WORK :
my_box = Box(default_box()) 
my_box.box_properties()
```

first one prints out : Blue Medium like I expected

second one gives me error :
**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'size'

Why?

Comment: try `Box(*default_box())`

Comment: Note that this behavior is not specific to constructors. You could have written a function `def foo(a,b): return a + b` and trying to do `foo(default_box())` would have crashed the same way.

Comment: Also FYI, if you want to read about this `*` behavior, you can search for "argument unpacking".

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answers helped me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `default_box()` returns *one* item, a two-element `tuple` which contains `first` and `second`. You need to unpack that into the arguments of `Box`

```py
x = default_box()
x
# ("Blue", "Medium")

# You can unpack the variable explicitly
my_box = Box(*x)

# or the function call
my_box = Box(*default_box())
```